# R: How to find the minimum value in row that has both numeric and non-numeric items?

Tags: r, row, numeric, min

I have a matrix - columns 1-371 are numeric, and columns 372-379 are non-numeric (ie. stores the age, gender information). I want to find the minimum value of each row of the numeric items (for each row, look over the 371 values).

I'm trying to make a count vector, so the code is:

```
count_a <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    if (min(data[i,][which(data$Age < age & data$Gender == gender)]) <= threshold) {
        count_a <- count_a+1
    }
}
```

However I keep getting this error: Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: If you have a mix of numeric and non-numeric columns, you don't have a matrix.  You likely have a data.frame.

Comment: You should probably describe in more detail what you're actually trying to do because from the looks of this code, you have several other things that are probably not correct. Specifically, your `which` statement probably isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you provided the structure of your data (`str(data)`). That being said, Tyler's answer (and baptiste's comment) are spot on.

Comment: Thanks - For each row, I'm trying to find the minimum value in the columns 1-371. I only want count_a to increase if the minimum value for row i is less than the threshold, and if the individual's age is less than the specified age, and the individual's gender is the specified gender.

Answer (score 2):

Using the CO2 data set try something like this:

```
NUM <-function(dataframe)dataframe[,sapply(dataframe,is.numeric)]
apply(NUM(CO2), 1, min)
```

Comment: `apply(Filter(is.numeric, CO2), 1, min)`